# (list) cannot be coerced to double within a function with dplyr

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I am trying to filter out outliers from my data. Here is the head from my data:

```
   X tile resolution topo max_height mean_height rugosity vertical_diversity  openness
1  9    1          5 high   19.41845   10.244725 5.533991          0.7931086 10.049369
2 21   10          5 high   22.49638   13.684197 5.707197          0.7863063  5.613547
3 33   11          5 high   16.96429    9.886287 4.190133          0.7471749 11.596492
4 45   12          5 high   19.83373   10.516013 5.297644          0.8006827  6.116738
5 57   13          5 high   21.69734   12.872438 6.009529          0.7797255  5.602573
6 69   14          5 high   23.77329   15.121994 5.777413          0.7651389  4.814283
```

When I used the following code:

```
lidar_summary_5_max_height_outlier_filter <- lidar_summary_5 %>% 
   filter(max_height <= mean(max_height)+2*sd(max_height) | max_height >= mean(max_height) - 2*sd(max_height))
```

I get the results I am looking for. However, since I am doing several iterations, I am trying to create a function that I can pass in each of several variables `max_height, mean_height, rugosity, vertical_diversity, openness` and different data files into. I made the following function:

```
outlier_filter <- function(dat, col){
  dat %>% 
    dplyr::filter(col <= (mean(col)+2*sd(col)) | col >= (mean(col) - 2*sd(col)))
}
```

where `dat` is the name of the data frame and `col` is the variable I am removing the outliers from. When I run this function, I get the following error:

```
 Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
 (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

And warning:

```
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(col) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I have tried to look up these errors separately, but the solutions I found did not help in this case. I'm not sure what's happening since the method works fine outside of the function but does not work in a function.

Comment: You might be interested in the dplyr programming vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html)

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the problem. Would it just be easier to do this in base R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `col` argument in your `outlier_filter` function needs to be evaluated in a non-standard context. Here's one way to do that, along the lines of the programming with dplyr vignette:

```
outlier_filter <- function(dat, col){
  col <- enquo(col)
  dat %>% 
    dplyr::filter(!!col <= (mean(!!col)+2*sd(!!col)) | !!col >= (mean(!!col) - 2*sd(!!col)))
}
```